# Plot Overlay MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, overlay, figure

How do you take one plot and place it in the corner (or anywhere for that matter) of another plot in MATLAB?

I have logarithmic data that has a large white space in the upper right-hand side of the plot.  In the white space I would like to overlay a smaller plot containing a zoomed in version of the log plot in that white space (sort of like a magnified view).

Before you tell me it can't be done, I would like to mention that I have seen it in action.  If my description is lacking, just let me know and I'll attempt to better describe it to you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An example:

```
x = 1:20;
y = randn(size(x));

plot(x, y,'LineWidth',2)
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), title('Plot Title')

h = axes('Position', [.15 .65 .2 .2], 'Layer','top');
bar(x,y), title('Bar Title')
axis(h, 'off', 'tight')
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485877/matlab-embed-zoom-in-subgraph-into-the-graph

Answer (score 8):

You can use `axes` properties `'position'` and `'units'` and make them overly. Pay attention to create small axes after big one or use `uistack()` function so that big does not hide small one.

What you can not do is to make an axes child of another one (like Mathworks do with `legend`). But you do not need it anyway.

For the second plot you have to use `axes` and `line` instead of `plot` and `hold on`.

Units as `'normalized'` (which is default) allows uniform resizable look when parent figure is being resized (e.g. manually maximized).