# How to overlay a pcolor plot with a contour plot that uses a different colormap?

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

Minimum example that does not achieve it:

```
[X,Y,Z] = peaks;
figure;
pcolor(X,Y,Z);
shading flat;
hold all;
axes;
contour(X,Y,Z);
colormap gray;  % this should only apply to the contour plot axes...
axis off;       % ... but it doesn't
```

This shows both the contour plot and the pseudo colour plot in the grayscale colourmap. However, what I want to achieve is only turning the contours gray.

This is just a minimalistic example, in reality the contour plot is of different data that has a different range, so two independent `caxis` settings are required as well.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744667/plot-overlay-matlab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix the problem by catenating two colormaps, and making sure that the values of the functions are such that they access the right part of the colormap:

```
cm = [jet(64);gray(64)];
figure,
pcolor(X,Y,Z)
shading flat
hold on
%# Z in the contour starts after the maximum
%# of Z in pcolor
contour(X,Y,Z-min(Z(:))+max(Z(:))+2,'LineWidth',2)
%# apply the colormap
colormap(cm)
```

[image]

For a more convenient solution, you may also want to have a look at [this file exchange pick of the week](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2009/07/24/using-multiple-colormaps-in-a-single-figure/)

Comment: Thank you. One may have to be careful if the function ranges differ by orders of magnitude though. I'll also have a look at the [freezeColors](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943) you linked to

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: Yes, it can be tricky to get the scaling of data/colormaps right. Also, it can be annoying if the datatip doesn't display the right values. My solution is really a workaround.