# color triangles with exceptions to some

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry, color-mapping

I am trying to draw a 2D mesh of triangles. I want to color each triangle according to a given array  `A` of positive scalars, one per triangle; For instance assume the `A` holds the area of each triangle, and I want large triangles to be pinker than smaller ones. I know how to do this:

```
patch('Faces',tri,'Vertices',V,'FaceColor','flat',
            'FaceVertexCData',A,...
            'CDataMapping','scaled');
colormap(pink);
```

However, I also have another boolean array `B`, one boolean per triangle. For instance it marks which of the triangles are isosceles triangles. 
In case a triangle is marked as `1` in `B`, I want to color it yellow.

I assume this can be achieved by something like `A(B==1)=-1`, changing the `colormap` and clever setting of `caxis`, but is this the most elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to skip coloring of some triangles (color them with one color), or use a different colormap for those triangles?

The first case is relatively simple for 2D plots. You can set A in those triangles to NaN, and patch will not draw them. Additionally, changing the background color of the plot will effectively show the non-drawn triangles in the color you want

```
A(B)=NaN;
set(gca,'Color',[1 0 0]); % red
```

If you want to use a different color, or a range of colors, you have to append the colormaps and set the values in A for the respective triangles to be 'larger enough' than A for any other triangles:

```
cmap = [colormap; [1 0 0]]; % red
colormap(cmap);
A(B) = max(A)+1;
```

No need to play with axis.

Otherwise, if you want to include two different color scales, you have to play with CData property of your patch plots, see a good tutorial [here](http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-GNRWEH/index.html) for drawing two plots, one in grayscale and one in color on the same figure.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457723/how-to-overlay-a-pcolor-plot-with-a-contour-plot-that-uses-a-different-colormap) post about how to plot two different data sets with two different colormaps. It is done by appending two colormaps and making sure that two datasets access distinct parts of the final colormap.

Comment: if `A=[1 2 3 10000]` then I don't think this trick will work. You suggest `A(B)=10001`, but `10001` and `10000` will map to the same color

Comment: @noam of course, that example was for A in [0,1] range. What if you make sure that A(B) is set to a 'large enough' value?

Comment: Of course it can be done like that, but these are exactly the kind of tricks I would have liked to avoid. 
And just for the sake of completeness, 'large enough' by itself isn't good enough, cause then if you take `A=[1 2 3]` and a 'large enough' addition, `A(B)=100000`, then now `1`, `2`, `3` map to the same color. It is not a hard computation to find the correct values, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @noam Then you can use the first method and change the plot background. See the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice trick but it would color the entire BG, no?

Comment: @noam Engire BG? The entire background of the plotting area (axes),  yes. Otherwise, there is no other way to do what you want except  concatenating color maps, playing with axes and CData property (see edited answer for more links). This is how it is normally done.