# Remove border around axes but keep the grid and ticklabels

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I want to get rid of the border around the axes, but keep the grid and the ticklabels.
In this question [Remove border around Matlab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166786/remove-border-around-matlab-plot) it was suggested to use

```
set(gca,'Ycolor',fig.color,'Ycolor',fig.color)
```

or

```
set(gca,'visible','off')
```

But both these options also make the label and the grid of the plot invisible.

```
set(gca,'box','off')
```

only turns of the top and right surrounding line of the plot. How can I remove the borders, but keep the grid and tick labels?